# What is the formal way to reply mail with requested attach file

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, tenses, formality

[image]

Is it grammatically correct, and a formal way to reply mail with my attached ID card? If I say **“I have attached my student ID card. Please check it”**

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly acceptable English, though you probably don't need the second sentence.

While what you have is perfectly fine, the following is perhaps a little bit nicer:

> Dear [name of recepient],
>
> As requested, I am attaching a scan of my student ID card. Should there be anything else you would need me to provide, please let me know.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> [your name]

Comment: Is it ok, if I say “As per your request, I have attached my student ID card”

Comment: Yes, that is fine too.

Comment: I agree that "Please check it" is not only not needed but may be mildly presumptuous, as you would be telling the recipient of your email what to do. The phrase "As per your request" is now considered obsolete business jargon. Better in my opinion to write, "As requested, I have attached a copy of my student ID card." Otherwise, a good question and a good answer,

Comment: @MarkHubbard Thanks! I've modified my answer.